# Expanding of Recurring Events from a Sharepoint Calendar doesn't work for a ViewFields Query

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, field, expand, recurrence

My post is a continue of [Expand Recurring Events from a Sharepoint Calendar over WebServices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376142/expand-recurring-events-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-over-webservices/12105181#12105181)

The problem is that expanding works while view fields query is null or empty. But since I set up some fields, the response doesn't match expectations.

The Lists.asmx service method,that I use, is

```
public System.Xml.XmlNode GetListItems(string listName, string viewName, System.Xml.XmlNode query, System.Xml.XmlNode viewFields, string rowLimit, System.Xml.XmlNode queryOptions, string webID)
```

When I use a viewFields value, presented below, the method doesn't expand recurrence events:

```
var viewFields = new XmlDocument();
viewFields.LoadXml(@"
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    </ViewFields>");
```

What's wrong with a viewFields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that view fields should contain additional fields **EventDate**, **EndDate**, **fRecurrence** and **RecurrenceData**. When this items absent, expanding doesn't work. So, if you want to retrieve a Category (for example), you should use the following ViewFields query:

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='fRecurrence ' />
    <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />
    <FieldRef Name='Category' />
</ViewFields>
```